# Filling web form fields but web page unable to detect text

Tags: excel, vba

I'm filling a web form using VBA, and I am able to fill text in the inputbox, but the webpage still is unable to detect the text and shows an error:
*"Error: Required Field - Please provide an answer"*

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Visible = True

URL = "https://npc.collegeboard.org/app/dartmouth/start"

objIE.Navigate URL

objIE.Document.getElementById("student.firstName").Focus
objIE.Document.getElementById("student.firstName").Value = "Tom"
```

Looks like theres some AngularJS running in the background, and it can't detect text fed in my VBA. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all after `objIE.Navigate URL` you should wait until the website is fully loaded and the IE is ready. This is done with the following:

```
objIE.Navigate URL 'this needs some time but VBA will continue excecuting the next statement qickly

Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Integer = 4
Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

'now IE is ready and the page is loaded.
```

But it might be that some JavaScript is not ready yet and this is not recognized by `objIE.Busy` Or `objIE.ReadyState`. So you can do a workaround:

```
Dim Obj As Object
Do While Obj Is Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Obj = objIE.Document.getElementById("student.firstName")
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop

'now `student.firstName` is accessible, and probably all the other fields are too.
```

This will try to access the field `student.firstName` if it is not there it will error. We suppress the error message using `On Error Resume Next` and jump back to `TryAgain` until it was found.

Note that this has one disadvantage: If there is a problem loading this site it will get stuck in this loop. So I recommend to get a timed cancel criterium like if this takes more than a minute cancel it and throw a error message.

Something like the following should work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim objIE As Object
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Visible = True

    Dim URL As String
    URL = "https://npc.collegeboard.org/app/dartmouth/start"

    objIE.Navigate URL

    Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Integer = 4
    Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Dim Obj As Object
    Do While Obj Is Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Obj = objIE.Document.getElementById("student.firstName")
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop


    objIE.Document.getElementById("student.firstName").Focus
    objIE.Document.getElementById("student.firstName").Value = "Tom"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank @Pᴇʜ. I am already doing all this (didn't include this to make it less verbose) - so the page is completely loaded before I start filling the form. My text gets filled in the textbox, but I still see an error on the page. Let me include an image with the question.

Comment: @user1771840 obviously the JavaScript behind that site triggers a keydown event. You can trick that by sending a key after setting the focus to that input box: After the `.Focus` line add `Application.SendKeys " "` to send a space into that box before you fill it with data.